# Working example of WIX script that registers help in MS Help 2.0 needed

Tags: wix

Can anybody give an example of WIX script to register custom help in visual studio help? I,ve searched for some tutorial, but the only thing that I found was VS schema reference. Everything I tried to do did not work. I use WIX 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer is not too late.

You're going to need:

- Your help collection (and some details, such as the internal collection name).
- [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- Some merge modules included as part of the Visual Studio SDK

First thing you want to do is create the Wix code that will hold your help collection.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="MyHelpDirectory">
  <Component Id="MyHelpCollection" Guid="INSERT_GUID_HERE">
    <File Id="MyHelpCollection.HxS" Source="..\MyHelpCollection.HxS" KeyPath="yes" />
    <File Id="MyHelpCollection.HxA" Source="..\MyHelpCollection.HxA" />  
    <File Id="MyHelpCollection.HxC" Source="..\MyHelpCollection.HxC" />
    <File Id="MyHelpCollection.HxT" Source="..\MyHelpCollection.HxT" /> 
    <File Id="MyHelpCollectionFIndex.HxK" Source="..\MyHelpCollectionFIndex.HxK" />
    <File Id="MyHelpCollectionIndex.HxK"  Source="..\MyHelpCollectionIndex.HxK" />
    <File Id="MyHelpCollectionKIndex.HxK" Source="..\MyHelpCollectionKIndex.HxK" />
    <File Id="MyHelpCollectionNamedUrlIndex.HxK" Source="..\MyHelpCollectionNamedUrlIndex.HxK" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Next, you want to make a copy of the **MSHelp2_RegTables_RTL_---_---.msm** merge module.  (It can be found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\HelpIntegrationWizard\MSHelp2) and open it with Orca.

Here you want to edit the **HelpNamespace** table in the merge module.  You're going to want to fill a record with the following information:

```
NamespaceKey    = Company.MyHelp.1033  (You can get this from the person who created your help collection.)
NamespaceName   = Company.MyHelp.1033
File_Collection = MyHelpCollection.HxC (Note that this is the Id attribute of the HxC file declared in the Wix code above.)
Description = My Help Collection
```

Now you want to edit the **HelpFile** table:

```
HelpFileKey  = MyHelp (Taken from the NamespaceKey above.)
HelpFileName = MyHelp
LangID       = 1033
File_HxS     = MyHelpCollection.HxS (Note that this is the Id attribute of the HxS file declared in the Wix code above.)
File_HxI     = MyHelpCollection.HxI (This is the Id attribute of the HxI file if your collection uses an HxI file.  The collections I use do not use HxI files.)
File_HxQ     = N/A
File_HxR     = N/A
File_Samples = N/A
```

Next you want to edit the **HelpFileToNamespace** table:

```
HelpFile      = MyHelp (Note that this must match the value defined in the HelpFile table above.)
HelpNamespace = Company.MyHelp.1033 (Note that this must match the value defined in the HelpNamespace table above.)
```

Finally, you want to edit the **HelpPlugin** table:

```
HelpNamespace_ = Company.MyHelp.1033  (Once again, keep this consistent)
HelpNamespace_Parent = MS_VSIPCC_v80  (For VS2005)
                     = MS.VSIPCC.v90  (For VS2008)
File_HxT       = MyHelpCollection.HxT (Id attribute for HxT file from Wix)
File_HxA       = MyHelpCollection.HxA (Id attribute for HxA file from Wix)
File_ParentHxT = FL_vsipcc_hxt_86880________.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8 (For VS2005)
               = FL_vsipcc_hxt_86880_86880_cn_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8.48273237_1399_45CF_801C_338E1AB00E90 (For VS2008)
```

You can now save your copy of the MSHelp2_RegTables_RTL_---_---.msm merge module.  It's probably a good idea to rename it to something like MyHelpCollection.msm.

Now you just have to include this merge module in your wix project, in addition to the VSIP merge module for the version of VS you're targeting:

```
<Merge Id="MyHelpCollectionMerge"
       Language="1033"
       Disk="1"
       SourceFile="PATH_TO_THE\MyHelpCollection.msm" />

<!-- For VS2005 -->
<Merge Id="VS2005VSIPMerge"
       Language="1033"
       Disk="1"
       SourceFile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\HelpIntegrationWizard\VS_2005\VSIPCC_Collection_Files_RTL_---_---.msm" />

<!-- For VS2008 -->
<Merge Id="VS2008VSIPMerge"
       Language="1033"
       Disk="1"
       SourceFile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\HelpIntegrationWizard\VS_2008\VSIPCC_Collection_Files_RTL_---_---.msm" />
```

Adapted from [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164959%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer.
I've already found what was wrong with my code.
It was a stupid bug with different names/IDs in different places.

As far as I understood, you do not use wix VS extension at all, so is it enough just to include modified merge module to my project?

Comment: Yes, the merge modules contain all the necessary information to install the help collections.  We were already using the merge modules when we switched from InstallShield to Wix, so we just continued using them.  I haven't looked into the Wix VS extension, but I imagine a lot of the behind the scenes stuff is probably taken from the merge modules.